# "rejected promise not handled within 1 second" vscode Extension API

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to write a simple extension for VS code that renames a selection to a given string. The app was bootstrapped with the extension generator: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-hello-world#_generate-a-new-extension

For this I use this code:

```
const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
    if (!editor) throw Error;

    const position = editor.selection.active
    const uri = editor.document.uri

    vscode.commands.executeCommand("vscode.executeDocumentRenameProvider", uri, position, "donkey")
        .then(edit => {
            if (!edit) throw Error;

            return vscode.workspace.applyEdit(edit);
        });
```

The command is bound to a keybinding. I launch the debugger with F5(launching an instance of vs code for debugging like in the tutorial: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-hello-world#_debugging-your-extension ). I then select a bunch of code in a file that I opened in that debugging instance and press my keybinding.

However, in the Debug Console I get "rejected promise not handled within 1 second". No error is thrown and since executeCommand is a Thenable, not a real Promise, I can't call catch() on it.

I tried to wrap the call in a try/catch block but with no success.
When i try other to do other stuff, like showing a message with vscode.window.showInformationMessage or prompt the user for input it works and I don't see the error.

I also tried to do the same with a Typescript version of the extension, but I get the same behavior.

I don't see what I am doing wrong, is there something I am missing ?

Comment: If it's not currently a real Promise, you could *convert* it to one yourself and `catch`, right?

Comment: Have you try not a try/catch, but `catch()`?

Comment: Yep, I still get the same result. I read that this can be caused by promises failing without calling reject() or something, however this comes from the vscode api function itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Thenable.then` takes two arguments: a success continuation and a failure continuation. You can use the failure continuation to make sure rejections are properly handled:

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand("vscode.executeDocumentRenameProvider", uri, position, "donkey")
    .then(edit => {
        if (!edit) throw Error;

        return vscode.workspace.applyEdit(edit);
    })
    .then(undefined, err => {
       console.error('I am error');
    })
```

This way, if `executeCommand`, the previous `then`, or `applyEdit` fail, the rejection is properly handled

Comment: Matt, you're a legend. I never thought of `.then(undefined, err => {` as the catch you have when you're not having a catch. This will greatly improve my code readability.

Comment: How weird. I had a similar problem when using `.then(fn, err=>{...})`, but not when using `.then(fn).catch(err=>{...})`. Shouldn't they be the same?